# JavaScript code is not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, mozilla

It is working like a charm on Chrome (latest version), IE, and Edge (I have to allow JavaScript on IE and Edge in order to work).

This code just validate an email if it is correct then it submits the form if it is wrong prevents the form action.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (validateEmail(email)) {

        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#cpa-form").submit();
        }, 5000);
        $("#error").text('Well done');
        $("#error").css({
            'background-color': '#dff0d8',
            'color': '#3c763d',
            'border-color': '#d6e9c6',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'padding': '15px',
            'margin-top': '5px',
            'margin-bottom': '5px',
            'border': '1px solid transparent',
            'border-radius': '4px'

        });
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").text('Something went wrong');
        $("#error").css({
            'background-color': '#f2dede',
            'color': '#a94442',
            'border-color': '#ebccd1',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'padding': '15px',
            'margin-top': '5px',
            'margin-bottom': '5px',
            'border': '1px solid transparent',
            'border-radius': '4px'

        });

    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cpa-form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="email">
      <br><br>
      <button  onclick="validate()" >button</button>
    
    </form>
    <span id="error"></span>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Have you used www.caniuse.com to verify all the functions you're using work in Firefox?

Comment: Could you copy the error?

Answer (score -1):

Stop using stupid calls from within the HTML, and defined `event` in the function-call. See updated JS-code in the snippet.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

$('button').click(function(event) {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (validateEmail(email)) {

        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#cpa-form").submit();
        }, 5000);
        $("#error").text('Well done');
        $("#error").css({
            'background-color': '#dff0d8',
            'color': '#3c763d',
            'border-color': '#d6e9c6',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'padding': '15px',
            'margin-top': '5px',
            'margin-bottom': '5px',
            'border': '1px solid transparent',
            'border-radius': '4px'

        });
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").text('Something went wrong');
        $("#error").css({
            'background-color': '#f2dede',
            'color': '#a94442',
            'border-color': '#ebccd1',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'padding': '15px',
            'margin-top': '5px',
            'margin-bottom': '5px',
            'border': '1px solid transparent',
            'border-radius': '4px'

        });

    }
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cpa-form">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="email">
      <br><br>
      <button>button</button>
    
    </form>
    <span id="error"></span>
```